# On a Mac, what is the hotkey associated with the image of an arrow pointing right ⇥?

Tags: macos, hotkeys

On a Mac, what is the hotkey associated with this image?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Top (Gray) image is <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Bottom (Bold) image is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

[Mac Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.danrodney.com/mac/index.html)

Comment: The pipe at the end is vital. `-->|` is "tab", but `-->` is just "right arrow".

Comment: FYI… Unicode provides for `RIGHT ARROW` character (→) at code point 8,594 (hex: `U+2192`). Also, I noticed the Keyboard Viewer applet that Apple provides is Sierra uses a dotted-stem right arrow on the screen display of the keyboard, similar to Unicode `RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH DOTTED STEM` (⤑) at code point 10,513 (hex `U+2911`).

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm not sure what you're trying to get at with your FYI. The symbol for Tab (in all post-Unicode OS X's) is and has been `U+21E5` ⇥ `RIGHTWARDS ARROW TO BAR`. The symbol's well-supported and is what is used in menubars to represent Tab. For what use are you suggesting `U+2911 RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH DOTTED STEM`? It doesn't exist in standard fonts on most current OS's.

Comment: @Kroltan Similarly unsure with what you're getting at. Visually, the line is "vital", but that's like saying a capital `K`'s left line is "vital", as otherwise it's a less-than symbol `<`. It's true as far as it goes, and you could probably make a human-readable document replacing all your `K`'s with `|<` (especially in a proportional font and/or using composing characters like this: <⃒) but, is it useful? You shouldn't simulate a Unicode glyph by deconstructing it into parts; just use the correct Unicode glyph in the first place, and in this case, that's `U+21E5` ⇥ `RIGHTWARDS ARROW TO BAR`.

Comment: Sorry for the distraction, I was thinking about people trying to display these symbols rather than interpreting them.

Comment: @Basil I think Kroltan’s comment may have been in response to the title of the question, which describes it as “an arrow pointing right”—that is a description of →, not of ⇥.

Answer (score 6):

As was already stated, it's the Tab key.

You can see all of the glyphs associated with keyboard keys using the Keyboard Viewer tool window.

(Note for PC keyboard users: Help button replaces Insert, Numpad + is split into two normal size keys, and Clear replaces Num Lock.)

[image: Keyboard Viewer]

Comment: Thanks!!! I am an avid user of hotkeys, and I know this will come in handy in the future!

Comment: FWIW, this is not Mac-specific; it's been on most keyboards for decades

Comment: @Sethmr It's not usually a hotkey. A hotkey is a key that triggers some system-wide action independent of the application you're currently using. Tab is just a normal control key, like Delete and Return, although Cmd-Tab is a hotkey for the application switcher.

Comment: When I said hotkey I was referring to the context of the application rather than what you are referring to. In my background I would refer to what you are mentioning as a macro. Either way, thank you for bringing that to my attention. I will try to use the terminology correct in the future.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition you mean the tab glyph is on most keyboards? For sure. The glyphs for command/control/option/clear/enter and fairly Mac specific though.

Comment: @Coxy: Yes. (Though based on the question title the OP is most interested in tab)